# nginx RoundCube+nginx cannot use imap on port 993

Tags: php, ssl, nginx, imap, roundcube

I'm configuring RoundCube on my server and I'd like to use secured protocols for send/receiving mails.

When installing RoundCube, it asks me for ports for smtp and imap, I chose 465 and 993 but when I run the tests it freezes and I get a Gateway Time-out 504 error.

If I use port 25 and 143, it works!

Is there something to do with nginx/php-cgi to use those protocols?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found what was wrong. If TLS or SSL is used you have to prefix the hostname with tls:// or ssl://, that was in the doc.